# How should I smooth / average semi-sparse service usage data used in a time series regression?

Tags: regression, time-series, smoothing, poisson-process, proportional-hazards

I am using time series regression and survival models to predict future user outcomes based on past usage trends.

I am dealing with a data set of daily service usage per user which, on a given day may capture (0..n) usages for a given user. In many cases, usage on day x is 0, but other days usage may be a positive integer. Daily usage seems to roughly follow a Poisson process, but with day-of-week trends (e.g., some users may use the service more on the weekends then during the week) and some seasonality.

The "spikiness" in the usage data due to the sparsity does not work well with regression or classification models, as the spikes and zeroes seem like noise instead of reflecting user usage trends.

What techniques would you suggest for smoothing semi-sparse time series usage data like this? I am considering: 1) basic moving averages, 2) exponential smoothing (to give higher weights to recent usage), 3) LOWESS smoothing, and 4) weekly averaging (i.e., the value for day X is sum or average of the whole week that day X resides in).

Are there better techniques for smoothing/aggregating this data? Is there a standard approach to smoothing semi-sparse usage data to be used in time series modeling?

Thanks!

Comment: i have never done/read anything like this before. Will it help to split that into two time series. One for time between days that has usage. The other one for amount of usage for days with nonzero usage. Then, try to find the relationship between these two things? That way, we don't need smoothing.